# Is the following proof of $(p \mid a) \land(p \not \mid b) \implies p \not \mid (a + b)$ correct?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

> **PROP** Let $p$ be a prime number, and $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then we have that:
>   $$
> (p \mid a) \land(p \not \mid b) \implies p \not \mid (a + b)
> $$

We proceed via proof by contradiction i.e. let's assume that:

$$
(p \mid a) \land(p \not \mid b) \implies p \mid (a + b)
$$

**PROOF**

- $p |a \iff \exists k_1 \in \mathbb{Z} : a = k_1 p$
- $p | (a + b) \iff \exists k_2 \in \mathbb{Z} : a + b = k_2 p$
- $k_2 p = a + b = k_1 p + b \iff k_2 p = k_1 p + b \iff b = (k_2 - k_1) p \iff p \mid b $
- But then we have $(p \not \mid b) \land (p \mid b)$, which is a contradiction.

$\square$

Comment: In fact, the implication is true regardless of whether or not $p$ is prime.

Comment: I hadn't realized that; there's nothing in the proof that is dependent on $p$ being prime. Good observation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct, but it's probably simpler to note that $p \not \mid b \Rightarrow \exists q_2, 0 \lt r \lt p \text{ such that } b=q_2p+r$ (in other words, $b$ has a positive remainder when divided by $p$), so $p \mid a \Rightarrow \exists q_1 ~(a=q_1p) \Rightarrow a+b=(q_1+q_2)p+r,$ and $0 \lt r \lt p \Rightarrow p \not \mid (a+b)$.

Comment: Of course! Thank you for the alternate proof XD.